# How to get the generated keys from a multiple insert in Java DB?

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

A multi-line insert, in the style

```
INSERT INTO table (col_a, col_b) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?)
```

In MySQL, when I call the getGeneratedKeys() method, the ResultSet correctly returns the created keys. In Java DB, only one key is returned.

I need to insert hundreds of rows, and with multiple insert it's much faster than adding one at a time. I can't use batch either, because Java DB doesn't return generated keys either.

Comment: You might have encountered https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-3609 .

Comment: And judging by the age of that report they don't plan to fix it, even though they have a contributed patch.